# Iphone Zxing: QR code scanning code not working in Release build

Tags: iphone, camera, zxing, scanning

I have integrated **Zxing** source code for QR code scanning in my Iphone project.

Until I built Zxing's project in Debug mode, it scans QR codes perfectly but in Release mode, the application is not able to scan the QR code from QR Image.

It just stops scanning QR codes without any error/exception. When we revert our build in Debug mode then it again scans perfectly.

I built Zxing's project in release mode with below mentioned settings:

```
1.  XCode: 4.0.1    Compiler: GCC 4.2                   Optimization Level: -O0
2.  XCode: 4.0.1    Compiler: GCC 4.2                   Optimization Level: -Os
3.  XCode: 4.0.1    Compiler: LLVM GCC 4.2              Optimization Level: -O0
4.  XCode: 4.0.1    Compiler: LLVM GCC 4.2              Optimization Level: -Os
5.  XCode: 4.0.1    Compiler: LLVM compiler 2.0         Optimization Level: -O0
6.  XCode: 4.0.1    Compiler: LLVM compiler 2.0         Optimization Level: -Os
7.  XCode: 4.2      Compiler: LLVM GCC 4.2              Optimization Level: -O0
8.  XCode: 4.2      Compiler: LLVM GCC 4.2              Optimization Level: -Os
9.  XCode: 4.2      Compiler: Apple LLVM compiler 3.0   Optimization Level: -O0
10. XCode: 4.2      Compiler: Apple LLVM compiler 3.0   Optimization Level: -Os
```

I have no clue where the issue is. Any help in this will be very helpful. Thanks..

Comment: Two things come to mind: a) different compile configuration in debug/release mode b) you treat the scanning result differently in debug/release mode. Are you using any preproccessor macros to distinguish different versions at compile-time?

Comment: The compile configurations are same for debug and release mode. I am treating the result same in either of the modes.  Also, I am not using any preprocessor macros.

Comment: This really seems strange. I'm not at my Mac at the moment. But i have an app with working ZXing implementtion on App Store. I'll check the compile settings as soon as i can if you don't get any answers.

Comment: rokjarc, I got the answer to this question. I was not using any preprocessor macros, on the other hand, I found that I have to add a preprocessor macro for release build "DEBUG". When I added this, my code works!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The [ZXing FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions) mentions that Release builds don't work with Xcode prior to 4.2 if you use llvm (llvm-gcc or clang) due to bugs in llvm. Both llvm-gcc and clang have been verified to work in Release mode with Xcode 4.2 and later, at least with `ScanTest` and `Barcodes`. I've still seen bugs with C++ and clang with Xcode 4.2 but they don't seem to affect ZXing, at least as seen with `ScanTest` and `Barcodes`.

The behavior with respect to the `DEBUG` symbol you mention is not repeatable on `ScanTest` or `Barcodes`. Neither of these projects defines `DEBUG`. Since defining `DEBUG` compiles in more debugging code, you may still be seeing an optimization bug.

You don't mention with architecture you're building for (`armv6` or `armv7`). There are reportedly problems with optimizations with `armv6` if you don't turn off Thumb mode. The projects in ZXing's svn do this; this change is not yet in any of the ZXing releases.

Comment: The project settings for ScanTest example and our project are same, the only difference is in the precompiler macro "DEBUG". It was already set for debug mode in my project by default, when I set this for release, it started working. Thanks for the explanation, however I got the code working yesterday.